# Web clips on Dashboard not always updating correctly in OS X (Lion)

Tags: macos, dashboard

I am having problems with Web Clips. Had the problem in OS X Leopard and now in Lion.

My problem is that I have clipped the "Major Stock Indexes" part of this page: http://online.wsj.com/mdc/page/marketsdata.html and sometimes it updates when I go to the dashboard, sometimes not (the timestamp in that section can be up to 24 hours old), which is frustrating. Going to the page in Safari shows me an updated page with a timestamp as of now, so it's not the page compatability with Safari that's the problem but I suspect something to do with web clips / the OS X dashboard functionality.

I have (of course) googled for a solution, but found none.

Any ideas of how I could solve it (or if not, how can one report a bug to Apple so they actually look at it/fix it)?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit a bug report [here.](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) It requires having a free Developer account. You can also submit feedback [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) which doesn't require a Developer account. I would suggest reporting on both.

Comment: Thank you. Will await to see if somebody has a solution and if not, will accept the bug report links as answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround until this gets fixed, you can click on the widget in question and hit <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd> to manually refresh it.

Comment: … to manually refresh it with a wicked animation, I would add.

Answer (score 0):

While Googling for the same solution (or workaround) I came across this page that offers something: http://mandogmachine.com/2010/10/how-to-fix-empty-dashboard-web-clips-in-snow-leopard/

> Here’s the workaround, step-by-step. It assumes that you already have
>   two or more Web Clips from the same site in your Dashboard and one or
>   more of them are coming up empty or they’re being resized so they
>   don’t display the correct part of the web page.
>
> First, in Safari go to the Safari menu item and click Reset Safari. In
>   the dialog that appears check at least the first four items and click
>   Reset. This will clean up Safari and generally make it less likely for
>   the problem to occur. Then, open Dashboard. Click on the widget that’s
>   not displaying correctly. Press cmd+R and immediately close Dashboard
>   while it’s reloading the widget by either clicking in an area without
>   a widget or by pressing the Dashboard key on your Apple Keyboard (F4).
>   You need to exit Dashboard while it’s reloading the Web Clip,
>   otherwise it won’t work. Reload Dashboard. The widget should show its
>   contents and it should stay that way. Repeat this process for every
>   Web Clip that comes up empty when you open Dashboard. Once you run
>   through the steps above, it seems to stick. At least that has been my
>   experience and I hope you’re as lucky

I am not sure how well it works, I just tried it myself, and will see over the next few days.  Hope it works, this has been nagging me for years!